# Why OnlyOnFaulted didn't catch the exeception at taskObject.Wait()?

Tags: c#, task

I'm studying and experimenting with task continuation, but I don't know how an exception can pass through the `TaskContinuationOption.OnlyOnFaulted`.

To what I know `Task.Wait()` provides a place where a program can catch any exceptions that may be thrown by a task but I don't know why it returns the exception but the task with `TaskContinuationOption.OnlyOnFaulted` continues.

```
Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {
    Console.WriteLine("T1 started");
    throw new Exception();
});

Task tFault = t1.ContinueWith((x)=> {
    Console.WriteLine("T fault started");

}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

Task t3 = tFault.ContinueWith((x)=> {
    Console.WriteLine("T3 started");
});
t1.Wait();
```

I'm expecting t1 to wait for the chained tasks to complete without throwing an exception.

Comment: "OnlyOnFaulted" means that the continuation `tFault` will run only if `t1` is faulted. It doesn't have *any* impact on `t1` itself

Comment: you should wait on t3, not t1.

Comment: [StartNew is Dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `await t1` you explicitly make a suspension point for `t1` which cause the exception to be re-thrown, it is expected behaviour([learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await)):

> If you await a task-returning async method that causes an exception,
>   the await operator rethrows the exception.

However, your expectations are partially correct because even `t1` throws exception `t2` and `t3` will be scheduled and eventually executed.

---

As a side note, there are a few problems with your code. You are using dangerous API, `StartNew` and `ContinueWith`. The problems are discussed, [start](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) and [continue](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

The recommendation is to use `async\await` instead of `ContinueWith`. Also, instead of `StartNew` better use `Run`.

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("T1 started");
    throw new Exception();
});

var t2 = ContinueAfterT1(t1);
var t3 = ContinueAfterT2(t2);

await t3;
```

where

```
async Task ContinueAfterT1(Task t1)
{
    try
    {
        await t1;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("T fault started");
    }
}

async Task ContinueAfterT2(Task t2)
{
    await t2;
    Console.WriteLine("T3 started");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tips. I was thinking of async\wait you recommended on what scenario should I choose async over blocking. Task.Run can run in synchronous right? But it runs in a background thread and can run in parallel. [C# Async Tips & Tricks](https://cpratt.co/async-tips-tricks/?utm_content=bufferbf041&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer&fbclid=IwAR1BNBazAVvAfN5CTOIzBgBYduwGBt9xLJcNV0QWsmTqjlLr6b-9IDAY98g)